# Using law of logic to simplify: (p → (q →r)) ↔ ((p∧q) → r) as much as possible.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Currently studying law of logic for discrete maths but simplify using law of logic has me completely blown away.

(p → (q →r)) ↔ ((p∧q) → r)

how would I simplify that as much as possible using laws of logic?
I literally have no idea even where to start...

I tried starting with equivalence law but that seemed to have just made the statement longer.

Any ideas / tips  would be great!

Comment: Use [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)#Formal_notation) and De Morgan.

Comment: This simplify to $\top$, since it's a tautology.

Comment: @GrandeDiMalto If you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) we have:
\begin{align}
&\hspace{3ex}(p → (q →r)) ↔ ((p∧q) → r)\\
&\equiv(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r)) ↔ (\neg (p∧q) \lor r)\tag*{Conditional equivalence}\\
&\equiv(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r)) ↔ ((\neg p\lor \neg q) \lor r)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
&\equiv(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r)) ↔ (\neg p\lor (\neg q \lor r))\tag*{Associative law}\\
&\equiv((\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r))\land(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r)))\tag*{Biconditional equivalence}\\
&\hspace{3ex}\lor(\neg(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r))\land\neg(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r)))\\
&\equiv(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r))\lor\neg(\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r))\tag*{Idempotent law}\\
&\equiv\top\tag*{Negation law}
\end{align}

Comment: Hmm, seems like we should be done after applying associativity, without applying the last three steps. Isn’t there a law like $(p\iff p)\equiv T$?

Comment: @RobPratt yes, if we have that law, then it's done, but it seems not listed in 'Logical equivalence', thats why i didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

What about natural deduction?  For "$\rightarrow$" as follows: Given the condition $p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r)$ and assume $\lnot\bigl((p\land q)\rightarrow r\bigr)$, that is $p\land q\land\lnot r$.  From the assumption we have $p$, $q$, and $\lnot r$.  From $p$ we conclude $q\rightarrow r$ from our condition and from here and $q$ we conclude $r$.  But we have know also $\lnot r$, hence our assumption was false.

Now try the other direction by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by the **exportation law,** the statement $p \to (q \to r)$ is logically equivalent to $(p \wedge q) \to r$. Of course, you can prove this using other (more fundamental) rules of inference, but if you are familiar with the exportation law then you may conclude immediately that the statement $p \to (q \to r) \leftrightarrow (p \wedge q) \to r$ is a tautology.